# Duende Identity Server v7 - Dynamic Providers

Tags: duende

I have a problem when implementing IS7 dynamic providers with database as a store (EF Core).
I already implemented dynamic providers using JSON store and that works fine.
But I can't do the same for Entity Framework store (i.e. using DB).

I'm already using ConfigurationDbContext. I applied migrations for tghat context and there are a number of tables related to configuration. I also manually created rows in IdentityProviders table (this table is created after mentioned migration is applied).
I'm constantly getting the exception with stack trace that contains:
*at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /*/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 51
at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /*/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27*

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Schemes'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__209_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Rsk.DynamicAuthenticationProviders.EntityFramework.Stores.AuthenticationSchemeStore.GetAllSchemes()
   at Rsk.DynamicAuthenticationProviders.DynamicAuthenticationSchemeProvider.GetRequestHandlerSchemesAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 51
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
```

I tried following steps from official Duende and Rsk docs.